# Pass variable value to array arguments in AngularJs 1.X

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, rootscope

I'm trying to launch external webpage in my angular application, I am using angular 1.4.X version. I have a array `items` which will be iterated to display as `md-buttons` with different icon, names. However i'm interested in adding url (href) to these buttons by passing arguments in the same array.

HTML:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div>
        <md-button target="_self" href={{item.url}} class="md-grid-item-content" ng-click="listItemClick($index)" ng-click="showRemedyGridSheet()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
            <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
```

JS:
Based on few logic i build url string and assign it to $scope. For example i have used below scenario,

```
$scope.items = [
    { name: 'Rebook', icon: 'rebook' , url:'rebookUrl'},
    { name: 'Puma', icon: 'puma'},
    { name: 'Nike', icon: 'nike' ,url:'nikeUrl'},
    { name: 'NewBalance', icon: 'nb' ,url:'nbUrl'},
  ];

  //build url
  $scope.rebookUrl= "http://www.reebok.co.uk/";
  $scope.nikeUrl= "http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/";
  $scope.nb="http://au.puma.com/";
```

How can i pass scope.rebookUrl or $scope.nb values to array $scope.items and then consume them in HTML page to launch to right url upon button click.

Comment: What's the problem of passing the url directly within the items array?

Comment: Putting two `ng-click` directives on one element won't work. The second `ng-click` directive will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after few trial and error i was able to find the solution, I hope it helps others.

HTML:

```
<md-button target="_self" ng-href={{item.url}} class="md-grid-item-content" ng-click="listItemClick($index);showRemedyGridSheet()">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
    <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
</md-button>
```

JS:

```
//build url first 
  $scope.rebookUrl= "http://www.reebok.co.uk/";
  $scope.nikeUrl= "http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/";
  $scope.nb="http://au.puma.com/";

// define url arguments in the array 
$scope.items = [
    { name: 'Rebook', icon: 'rebook' , url:$scope.rebookUrl},
    { name: 'Puma', icon: 'puma'},
    { name: 'Nike', icon: 'nike' ,url:$scope.nikeUrl},
    { name: 'NewBalance', icon: 'nb' ,url:$scope.nbUrl},
  ];
```

Two thing i noticed, the url argument in an array should be passed with `$scope.XXX` without any `quotes`. Second thing was i declared the array first and build the url, so the array url argument wasn't loaded with the values.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use 2 ng-clicks. You can combine them like this:

```
<md-button target="_self" href="{{$scopeitem.url}}" class="md-grid-item-content"
ng-click="listItemClick($index);showRemedyGridSheet()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
            <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
        </md-button>
```

Second, you can try to use array notation on the scope variable. So in your controller do something like this:

```
$scope.getUrl= function(item){
    return $scope[item.url];
};
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<md-button target="_self" href="{{getUrl(item)}}" class="md-grid-item-content"
ng-click="listItemClick($index);showRemedyGridSheet()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
            <div class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </div>
        </md-button>
```

Sorry, I don't have time at the moment to whip this up in Plunker

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: How would you suggest calling getUrl for each item ? I don't think it will iterate if used outside the ng-repeat ?

Comment: I would really like to get away from the getUrl function, but I am not sure about accessing the $scope variable in the HTML. A better way would be to put all your URLs on an object like $scope.urls. Then you could use urls[item.ur] instead of the function.

Comment: So that would be different object than $scope.items, if so i have to pick by the the index value. But i don't see it solves the main problem of retrieving value from `$scope.rebookUrl` etc

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there, but there are three slight issues with your code:

1. As pointed out by @georgeawg, you cannot declare two `ng-click` attributes on the same element. You can simply call both functions: `ng-click="listItemClick($index); showRemedyGridSheet();"`. Or, alternatively, you can just move the `showRemedyGridSheet()` call into the `listItemClick` definition.
2. You must declare and initialize the `$scope.[url]` variables before you use them in the `$scope.items` array.
3. The `href` attribute is plain HTML, and it's possible that the link could be clicked before Angular has had an opportunity to interpolate `{{item.url}}` properly. It is therefore safer to use `ng-href` here instead.